# True Or False with a proof

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

If A and B are 2 x 2 matrices is the sum of the terms on the main diagonal of $AB – BA$ is zero?

How to solve it?

Comment: Term to look up: "trace"

Comment: could you explain "trace" for me? :(

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $a,b,c,d$ be the entries of one matrix, and $w,x,y,z$ be the entries of another. Actually compute $AB$ and $BA$ and observe that everything cancels.

Comment: so it is false? the main diagonal at last is in perspective {by-xc cx-yb}

Comment: I just checked my computation on paper, and it will work.

Comment: can you check the image i provided? sorry for bothering

Comment: @TamaraSalah If you add up those terms, they cancel, as they are each other's negatives.